# ORACLE: How to select previous different value?

Tags: oracle

I have table that stores employee job name, it has the following columns:
id; date_from; date_to; emp_id; jobname_id; grade;

Each emp_id can have many consecutive records with the same jobname_id due to many grade changes.
How can I select previous different jobname_id omitting those that are the same like the most current one?

Comment: can we assume that date_to decides which is the most recent job?  (even if it is in future). or do you need some calculation on the range (from-to) to decide that? also if there is only one jobname_id that has no previous, do you want it selected? or do you want no selection for it?

Comment: most recent job in my understanding is the current one, I do not take into consideration those with future date_from dates. The perfect scenario is that if the current jobname_id is the only one record then "null" value shall be returned. I should also take into consideration employees that left company with the most recent jobname_id that has date_to in the past - in that case this would be the previous jobname_id because there is no jobname_id in between date_from and sysdate...

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the FIRST_VALUE() analytic function to identify each employee's current job.  It then filters for all the jobs which dfon't match that one:

```
select distinct id
       , jobname_id
from ( select id
              , jobname_id
              , first_value(jobname_id) over (partition by id 
                                               order by from_date desc) as current_job
       from employee
       where emp_id = 1234 )
where jobname_id != current_job
order by id, jobname_id 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for your issue:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       e1.emp_id,
       e1.jobname_id
  FROM employee e1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1
          FROM employee e2
         WHERE e1.emp_id = e2.emp_id
           AND SYSDATE BETWEEN e2.date_from 
                           AND NVL(e2.date_to, SYSDATE + 1));
```

(This asumes your table is named "employee" and emp_id is the PK value).

It selects unique emp_id, jobname_id values where the emp_id, jobname_id values are not current.

EDIT: I agree with Chin Boon that fundamentally this is a design issue and perhaps that should be addressed rather than working around the problem.